# PPPOE doesn't work on 15.04 (intel I217-V)

Tags: internet, 15.04, pppoe

I was trying to setup DSL to surf the Internet.
After I set up my username and password to the configuration.
I clicked the connet and it does not work.....

I used the some way to successfully drive ubuntu 14.10 on other computer...

I don't know how I should to drive Intel I217-V on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about 14.10, but to connect to PPPoE/DSL using NetworkManager on 15.04 requires installing the `pppoe` package, which (for some reason) was not installed by default on my Lubuntu 15.04.

```
sudo apt-get install pppoe
```

I've reported this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1455219